# Handling files order regarding concatenation with WebPack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, webpack

A good practice when using Angular is to separate module definition from each usage of this module (one usage per file).

For instance:

```
//HomeModule.js
angular.module('home', []);

//HomeService.js
angular.module('home')
 .service('HomeService', HomeService);
```

Classic issue is regarding files concatenation:
If `HomeService.js` is injected before `HomeModule.js` in the final file, this would result in this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Using gulp, there's a handy [gulp-angular-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort) that could manage it for us.

How to handle Angular files ordering **when dealing with WebPack** and files concatenation, to prevent this kind of disorder?

Comment: I think I found a pretty solution, thanks to Webpack modules. github.com/nazar/angular-es6-webpack-seed/blob/master/src/app/… Each component are declared near the module declaration, but each component's implementation is within it's own distinct file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree, this line `.service('HomeService', HomeService);` belongs to module, not service. So you have following setup:

HomeService.service.js:

```
export default ['$timeout', ..., ($timeout, ...) => { /*some code*/}]
```

HomeModule.js:

```
import HomeService from 'HomeService.service.js'

angular.module('home', [])
 .service('HomeService', HomeService);
```

You do not have any problems with order in this case.